# ggplot2 stacked bar not ordering by manually-defined factor order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to manually define the order of the items in each stacked bar. From all of the research I've done, I should be able to do this by manually defining the order of these factors prior to plotting. For some reason I have not been successful.

Here is the raw data:

```
df <- structure(list(cross_valid = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 3.546, 0, 0, 0, 28.0927688833, 4.689, 0.4887, 1.134, 
20.886690705, 16.8620595883, 14.8086, 18.648, 20.5713, 44.046
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("cross_valid", 
"variable", "value"))
```

Looks like:

```
> head (df)
  cross_valid variable value
1           1        a 0.000
2           2        a 0.000
3           1        b 0.000
4           2        b 0.000
5           1        c 3.546
6           2        c 0.000
```

Current order and levels of `df$variable`:

```
> df$variable
 [1] a a b b c c d d e e f f g g h h i i
Levels: a b c d e f g h i
```

Now I change the order of `df$variable`:

```
df$variable <- factor(df$variable, levels = unique(c("i","a","b","e","g","f","h")),ordered=TRUE)
```

Now plot the graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + geom_bar(data=df,aes(x=cross_valid,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
p <- p + scale_fill_manual("",values=c('a'='darkred','b'='blue','c'='black','d'='darkolivegreen1','e'='green','f'='darkorchid','g'='yellow',
                                       'h'='snow4','i'='darkgray'),
                           breaks=c('i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'),
                           labels=c('i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'))
p
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

I defined 'i' and 'h' to be on opposite ends of the bar, yet they are still next to each other. Are there any ideas on why this might be happening? Maybe something is odd with my data?

Thanks

-al

EDIT 1:

Following @MrFlick's advice I removed breaks, but still find that 'i' and 'h' are still next to each other in the bar, even though the levels have defined them to be at opposite ends of the bar.

```
> df$variable
 [1] a a b b c c d d e e f f g g h h i i
Levels: i < a < b < c < d < e < g < f < h
```

Edited plot code:

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_bar(data=df,aes(x=cross_valid,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
p <- p + scale_fill_manual("",values=c('a'='darkred','b'='blue','c'='black','d'='darkolivegreen1','e'='green','f'='darkorchid','g'='yellow',
                                       'h'='snow4','i'='darkgray'))
p
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Your `scale_fill_manual` with `breaks=` overrides the default order of the factors.

Comment: @MrFlick taking out the breaks= didn't seem to help. See EDIT 1.

Comment: Two things: (1) You don't need `unique` or `ordered` in your factor call, but you _do_ need to list all the original levels; as it is you are introducing NAs, (2) try `aes(...,order = variable)`.

Comment: @joran, `order=variable`, did the trick.

Comment: @AlK Conveniently documented at the very bottom of `?aes_group_order`. ;) Who wouldn't find it there...? <sarcasm>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
df$variable <- relevel(df$variable, "i")

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df,aes(x=cross_valid,y=value,fill=variable,order=variable),stat='identity') +
  scale_fill_manual("",
                    values=c('a'='darkred','b'='blue','c'='black','d'='darkolivegreen1','e'='green','f'='darkorchid','g'='yellow','h'='snow4','i'='darkgray'),
                    breaks=c('h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a','i'),
                    labels=c('h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a','i'))
p
```

I used `relevel` to change factor level order and added an `order` parameter to the `aes`.
Edit: Changing the order of `breaks` and `labels` also adjusts the legend accordingly.

[image]

Second Edit: Sorry, solution was already posted in comments above, didn't see that before answering...